# Strange situation Sencha Architect EXT JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

Well I don't know even where to start. Opening my code after some period of time everything seems to be broken. My app gets build without errors but it doesn't do nothing. I have added several methods (like beforerender) and several button click events to test it, but it does not react to anything. The debug tools from all the browser do not give any errors. It seems like that some reference or method was accidentally deleted... I know that the question is maybe vague bit I'm really stuck here.

Could anyone just point to me to the right direction of solving this problems.

Comment: that's annoying indeed I came across similar issues with architect.. but no one can 'guess' what's the actual problem. You'll have to try and analyse the code... there must be something missing.. try switching out the `ext-all.js` file with `ext-all-dev.js` it 'll give you more (meaningfull) error messages

Comment: How can I do that in the Architect?

Comment: don't think you can configure that in architect (sadly enough), but you can go to your rendered index.html page and do it manually. check if the ext-all.js is present and replace it with : `<script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/ext-all-dev.js"></script>`

Comment: It is the same. No errors found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a controller reference missing.